# CasperJS doesn't show the characters correctly after screenshot via captureBase64

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using captureBase64 to take a screenshot and show it in my website. I have a two test environment running over Windows and Linux in the first I use Wampserver and the other Apache 2.4.6 + php 5.5 both executes the same casperjs code.

When I Using Linux I don't know what happened but the strings/characters doesn't appear correctly some times just what it show are squares character below my code:

```
1. CasperJS

    this.click(x(btDetalhes));
    this.wait(3000); // Descomentar se der ERROR
        casper.waitForResource("Dúvidas", function detalhesPedido(screenShot) {
            return screenShot;
                }, function onReceived() {
                    this.log('Wait...');            
                    myScreenShot = this.captureBase64('png', '#ctl00_Conteudo_rptListaCompras_ctl00_pnlPrincipal', {format: 'png', quality: 100});
                });

    // Logout & Exit
    casper.thenOpen(url_logout, function logout() {
         // Check if exists screenshot
            if (myScreenShot !== "") {
                this.echo("data:image/png;base64," + myScreenSHot).exit();
            } else {
                this.echo('Sorry!')exit('1601');
            }
    }).run();
```

I'm using casperjs-1.1.0-beta3 and phantomjs-1.9.8 with CentOS 7.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer what was obviously is so clear!

I make a php call back to casper script and after the script done a return a JSON to php.

After install the php-gd all strings/characters appear correctly.

Thanks